# Using Selenium in Python, is there a way to make the webdriver/browser a "recognized device" when signing in to an online account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a Python program with Selenium that will open a browser, log in to my credit union account, and copy the transactions to a spreadsheet for me to manipulate further.

When I log in to my account from a new device, it requires further identification by sending a code to my phone or email.

[Secure Login 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0jOK.png)
[Secure Login 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzUkg.png)

I can run my script and manually take care of the extra verification, but even if I choose to register the browser as a trusted device, it always asks for extra verification each time I run the script.

I thought I could have it send a code to my email, and then fetch the email, and then enter the code, but that seems more complicated than necessary.

Is there a way to successfully register the browser being run by Selenium?

Perhaps there some ID within the browser that the website would use to register a device, and Selenium uses a new one each time?

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code so far, I know it's pretty basic right now: (written in Python 3.8)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#Open Chrome Browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'path to my driver...\chromedriver.exe')

#Navigate to CU
browser.get("CU's Website")

#Let website load, not sure if this is necessary or not
time.sleep(3)

#Get Paths for Input Fields (Is there a way to hardocde these paths? Does it matter?)
field_user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#userid")
field_password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#password")
field_enter = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#LoginForm > input[type=image]:nth-child(8)")


#Enter Username
field_user.send_keys('My username')

#Enter Password (What is a good/secure way to store password here?
field_password.send_keys('My password')

#Submit Credentials
field_enter.click()
```

Comment: Hello my friend. Did you find solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My workaround was to also automate fetching a 2FA code from my email to enter on the site, but that's not really ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each new session generates a new temporary `browser profile`. I had a similar issue when trying to login to [appstoreconnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login).

[image: phones]

[image: apple code]

You can configure a browser to use a static(or dynamic) profile using `options`. Here is an example:

```
# run.py
import logging
import os
from logging.config import dictConfig
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['debug_console_handler'],
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'debug_console_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
        },
    },
})


def main():
    options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    login_url = 'https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login'
    logging.info('login to %s', login_url)
    driver.get(login_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'aid-auth-widget-iFrame')))
    frame = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'aid-auth-widget-iFrame')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sign-in')))
    logging.info('set user and password')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'account_name_text_field').send_keys(os.environ['USER'])
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sign-in').click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sign-in')))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password_text_field').send_keys(os.environ['PASSWORD'])
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sign-in')))
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sign-in').click()
    sleep(5)

    logging.info('Browser check')

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//phones')
    except NoSuchWindowException:
        logging.info('Browser already trusted')
        exit()

    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[phone-id='{}']".format(2)).click()
    app_code = input('Apple ID code from SMS: ')
    logging.info('set code and click "Trust" button')
    for index, number in enumerate(app_code):
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-index='{}']".format(index)).send_keys(number)

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[3]')))
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[3]').click()
    logging.info('Done')
    sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Lets prepare docker container with `selenium`:

```
mkdir profile
chmod 777 profile
export USER={USER_NAME}
export PASSWORD={PASSWORD}

docker run -d -p 4444:4444 \
           -p 7900:7900 \
           -e USER -e PASSWORD \
           -v $(pwd)/profile:/profile \
           --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/run.py,target=/scripts/run.py \
           --name ff \
           --shm-size="2g" \
           selenium/standalone-firefox:4.5.0-20220929

docker exec -it ff bash -c 'sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y python3-pip && pip install selenium==4.5.0'
docker exec -it ff bash -c 'sudo touch geckodriver.log && sudo chmod 777 geckodriver.log'
```

Let's check:

```
docker exec -it ff bash -c 'python3 /scripts/run.py'
# login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login
# set user and password
# Browser check
# Apple ID code from SMS: ******
# set code and click "Trust" button
# Done
```

Let's try one more time:

```
docker exec -it ff bash -c 'python3 /scripts/run.py'
# login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login
# set user and password
# Browser check
# Apple ID code from SMS: ******     <---------  still needs a code
# set code and click "Trust" button
# Done
```

Now let's add a few `options` into `run.py`:

```
options.add_argument('-profile')
options.add_argument(os.path.join(os.environ['PWD'], 'profile'))
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0')
```

and repeat the steps:

```
docker exec -it ff bash -c 'python3 /scripts/run.py'
# login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login
# set user and password
# Browser check
# Apple ID code from SMS: ******
# set code and click "Trust" button
# Done

docker exec -it ff bash -c 'python3 /scripts/run.py'
# login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login
# set user and password
# Browser check
# Browser already trusted     < --------  remembered me

tree profile  # browser profile files
# profile
# ├── addonStartup.json.lz4
# ...
# ├── user.geckodriver_backup
# ├── user.js
# ├── webappsstore.sqlite 
# ├── WebDriverBiDiActivePort
# └── xulstore.json
```

So, all you need is just to create a `profile` and specify the path using `options`